# use other server command after login using openssl in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I am developing a ruby on rails project to create email using Opensrs Api. For now, I can use terminal to create email via api and want to integrate that api command to my Rails Project, but I get stuck.

The problem is not able to run api command opensrs server to create Email after i have logged in that server using openssl.

I have read through [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) for using openssl with ruby code and [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Buffering.html) for OpenSSL::Buffering. Yet after I run the following code, it seem not working .

Any suggestions for running opensrs command after log in using openssl?

Here is the code in my controller:

```
    require 'socket'
    require 'openssl'
    p "1---------------"

    tcp_client = TCPSocket.new 'abc.com', 4449

    context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new tcp_client, context

    ssl_client.connect

    ssl_client.write_nonblock "hello ========"
    ssl_client.print "print hello ========"
    ssl_client.write "write hello ========"

    ssl_client.write_nonblock "ver ver='3.6'"
    p ssl_client.readlines
    p "2---------------"
```

In the console, it response:

1---------------

2---------------